# how to set data with timestamp type as primary key in laravel 7?

Tags: laravel, timestamp, laravel-7, laravel-migrations

**I want to set the played column as primary key while keeping its type as timestamp.**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('tb_played', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedInteger('artist_id');
        $table->foreign('artist_id')->references('artist_id')->on('tb_artist');
        $table->unsignedInteger('album_id');
        $table->foreign('album_id')->references('album_id')->on('tb_album');
        $table->unsignedInteger('track_id');
        $table->foreign('track_id')->references('track_id')->on('tb_track');
        $table->timestamp('played');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: Never add data/code as images. Instead paste them as text

Comment: sorry, I'll add the code as text

Comment: Using a **timestamp** as your `primary key` is a terrible idea. Life is just much easier to use the standard auto incrementing integer as your primary key, especially since there is no guarantee that two timestamps are absolutely unique from one another.